# Events 2027, 2026 and 8231 for Exchange 2003 SP2

Tags: exchange-2003

I am getting the events 2027, 8231 and  errors logged every few minutes on our exchange server.  The errors is resulting from a missing file "proxygen.dll", I don't have another Exchange server to copy it from and FAX is not listed in the Exchange recipient policy.

The only reference to proxygen.dll I can find is in teh Exchange SDK, and I think it has to be compiled first.

Any idea how to fix this or where I can get the proxygen.dll?

Example Event Messages:

---

Event Type: Error
Event Source: MSExchangeSA
Event Category: General 
Event ID: 2037
Date: 
Time:  2:16:29 PM
User:  N/A
Computer: EXCHANGE
Description:
The file version of '\address\FAX\i386\proxygen.dll' installed on the local server is not current. Unable to locate a correct version on any server in the site.

For more information, click http://www.microsoft.com/contentredirect.asp.

---

Event Type: Error
Event Source: MSExchangeSA
Event Category: General 
Event ID: 2027
Date:  
Time:  2:16:29 PM
User:  N/A
Computer: EXCHANGE
Description:
Unable to generate the e-mail address. Unable to load address module 'C:\Program Files\Exchsrvr\address\FAX\i386\proxygen.dll' for address type 'FAX'. Error 0xc007007e.

For more information, click http://www.microsoft.com/contentredirect.asp.

---

Event Type: Error
Event Source: MSExchangeAL
Event Category: Service Control 
Event ID: 8231
Date:  9/14/2009
Time:  
User:  N/A
Computer: EXCHANGE
Description:
Permanent failure reported by policy group provider for 'CN=Recipient Policies,CN=Company,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=com':'MAD.EXE', error=8000ffff.  Taking provider offline.

For more information, click http://www.microsoft.com/contentredirect.asp.

---

Event Type: Information 
Event Source: MSExchangeSA 
Event Category: General  
Event ID: 2036 
Date:  9/14/2009 
Time:  2:16:29 PM 
User:  N/A 
Computer: EXCHANGE 
Description: The file version of 'C:\Program Files\Exchsrvr\address\FAX\i386\proxygen.dll' installed on the local server is not current. Looking at servers in the site for a current version.

For more information, click http://www.microsoft.com/contentredirect.asp.

Guess this is a unique issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this using the following:

Click Start, point to Programs, point to Windows 2003 Support Tools, click Tools, and then click ADSI Edit. Click the Configuration container. Click CN=Configuration,DC=Domain Components. Click CN=Services, click CN=Microsoft Exchange, click CN=Organization Name, and then click CN=Address Lists Container. Click CN=Recipient Update Services. In the right pane, right-click the domain Recipient Update Service, and then click Properties. In the Select a property to view list, click gatewayProxy. In the Value(s) box, click the address type that stays populated, and then click Remove